# Fanuc Focas target spindle speed

Tags: c#, cnc

Does anyone know if it's possible to read the target spindle speed through Fanuc Focas?
I can easily read the actual spindle speed, but i would like to read the target spindle speed.

I have access to PMC programming on the machine as well if this is needed.

I can't see any built-in functionality for this.

I read the documentation at
https://www.inventcom.net/fanuc-focas-library/general/fwlib32